# call different window classes into a main window in PQt5 - python

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

I have a functional code running 2 procedures and display 2 windows separately. each procedure generates its own window. I would like to choose the procedure to be displayed or have both in a main window. the 2 options are of interest. I tried to define a window where i could call each items but since the generation of the individual windows (Mainwindow_1 and 2) belong to a class already defining a window i don't know how to proceed to display only one window at a time upon clicking the corresponding item.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
import sys
import random
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta
import time
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from pymeasure.log import console_log
from pymeasure.display.Qt import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# import GUItest


from pymeasure.display.windows import ManagedWindow
from pymeasure.experiment import Procedure, Results
from pymeasure.experiment import IntegerParameter, FloatParameter, Parameter, ListParameter

class RandomProcedure_1(Procedure):

    iterations = IntegerParameter('Loop Iterations', default=10)
    delay = FloatParameter('Delay Time', units='s', default=0.2)
    seed = Parameter('Random Seed', default='10')
    mode = IntegerParameter('Measurement mode : must be 2 or 4 probes', default=2)
    # instruments = ListParameter('procedure to run ', ('RandomProcedure_1', 'RandomProcedure_2'), default='RandomProcedure_1')  # devices under test

    DATA_COLUMNS = ['Mode', 'Iteration', 'Timecode', 'Elapsed', 'Random Number']

    def startup(self):
        log.info("Setting the time of the random number generator")
        random.seed(self.seed)

    def execute(self):
        log.info("Starting the loop of %d iterations" % self.iterations)
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        for i in range(self.iterations):
            timecode = dt.now()
            elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
            data = {
                'Mode': self.mode,
                'Iteration': i,
                'Timecode': timecode,
                'Elapsed': elapsed,
                # 'instruments': self.instruments,
                'Random Number': random.randint(1, 50)
            }
            self.emit('results', data)
            log.debug("Emitting results: %s" % data)
            sleep(self.delay)
            if self.should_stop():
                log.warning("Caught the stop flag in the procedure")
                break

class RandomProcedure_2(Procedure):

    iterations = IntegerParameter('Loop Iterations', default=15)
    delay = FloatParameter('Delay Time', units='s', default=0.1)
    seed = Parameter('Random Seed', default='40')
    mode = IntegerParameter('Measurement mode : must be 2 or 4 probes', default=2)
    # instruments = ListParameter('procedure to run ', ('RandomProcedure_1', 'RandomProcedure_2'), default='RandomProcedure_1')  # devices under test

    DATA_COLUMNS = ['Mode', 'Iteration', 'Timecode', 'Elapsed', 'Random Number']

    def startup(self):
        log.info("Setting the time of the random number generator")
        random.seed(self.seed)

    def execute(self):
        log.info("Starting the loop of %d iterations" % self.iterations)
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        for i in range(self.iterations):
            timecode = dt.now()
            elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
            data = {
                'Mode': self.mode,
                'Iteration': i,
                'Timecode': timecode,
                'Elapsed': elapsed,
                # 'instruments': self.instruments,
                'Random Number': random.randint(1, 100)
            }
            self.emit('results', data)
            log.debug("Emitting results: %s" % data)
            sleep(self.delay)
            if self.should_stop():
                log.warning("Caught the stop flag in the procedure")
                break

class MainWindow_1(ManagedWindow):

    def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow_1, self).__init__(
                procedure_class=RandomProcedure_1,
                inputs=['mode', 'iterations', 'delay'],
                displays=['mode', 'iterations', 'delay'],
                x_axis='Iteration',
                y_axis='Random Number',
                # sequencer=True,  # Added line
                # sequencer_inputs=['iterations', 'delay', 'seed', 'mode'],  # Added line
                # # inputs_in_scrollarea=True
                # sequence_file="gui_sequencer_example_sequence.txt",  # Added line, optional
            )
            self.setWindowTitle('RandomProcedure_1')
            self.count = 0

    def queue(self, *, procedure=None):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if procedure is None:
            procedure = self.make_procedure()
        filename = '.\\test\\experiment_1\\' + str(dt.now().strftime("%m%d%Y")) + '_' + 'mode_' + str(self.count) + '.csv'  # working directory
        log.info("Constructing the Results with a data file: %s" % filename)
        results = Results(procedure, filename)
        experiment = self.new_experiment(results)
        self.manager.queue(experiment)

class MainWindow_2(ManagedWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow_2, self).__init__(
            procedure_class=RandomProcedure_2,
            inputs=['mode', 'iterations', 'delay'],
            displays=['mode', 'iterations', 'delay'],
            x_axis='Iteration',
            y_axis='Random Number',
            # sequencer=True,  # Added line
            # sequencer_inputs=['iterations', 'delay', 'seed', 'mode'],  # Added line
            # # inputs_in_scrollarea=True
            # sequence_file="gui_sequencer_example_sequence.txt",  # Added line, optional
        )
        self.setWindowTitle('RandomProcedure_2')
        self.count = 0

    def queue(self, *, procedure=None):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if procedure is None:
            procedure = self.make_procedure()
        filename = '.\\test\\experiment_2\\' + str(dt.now().strftime("%m%d%Y")) + '_' + 'mode_' + str(self.count) + '.csv'  # working directory
        log.info("Constructing the Results with a data file: %s" % filename)
        results = Results(procedure, filename)
        experiment = self.new_experiment(results)
        self.manager.queue(experiment)

# in this window i would like to call only one procedure upon choosing the name on the list or have both displayed in one window
# as it is only one window 2 appears and i cannot trigger the queue experiemnts
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.listwidget = QListWidget()
        self.listwidget.insertItem(0, "RandomProcedure_1")
        self.listwidget.clicked.connect(self.MainWindow_1)
        self.listwidget.insertItem(1, "RandomProcedure_2")
        self.listwidget.clicked.connect(self.MainWindow_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
    #
    def MainWindow_1(self):
        window_1 = MainWindow_1()
        window_1.show()
        window_1.exec_()

    def MainWindow_2(self):
        window_1 = MainWindow_2()
        window_1.show()
        window_1.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # window_1 = MainWindow_1()
    # window_2 = MainWindow_2()
    # window_1.show()
    # window_2.show()
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `void QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)`
The documentation states that :

**this signal is emitted with the specified item when a mouse button is clicked on an item in the widget.**

And that's what you are expecting specifically from your code. Don't use a two functions on a single method.

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you connected to the `clicked` to two functions, so once you click *any* item the first connected function (`MainWindow_1()`) is executed and the second will not start until the first is returned (after its `exec_` is returned in turn).

You should connect to a single slot and differentiate according to the parameter of the signal. Since you're using a QListWidget, you can use [`itemClicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked), which returns the QListWidgetItem that has been clicked, then you can run the relative window/procedure accordingly.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.listwidget = QListWidget()
        self.procedureItem1 = QListWidgetItem('RandomProcedure_1')
        self.listwidget.addItem(self.procedureItem1)
        self.procedureItem1 = QListWidgetItem('RandomProcedure_2')
        self.listwidget.addItem(self.procedureItem2)
        self.listwidget.itemClicked.connect(self.startProcedure)
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

    def startProcedure(self, item):
        if item == self.procedureItem1:
            window = MainWindow_1()
        elif item == self.procedureItem2:
            window = MainWindow_2()
        else:
            return
        window.show()
        window.exec_()
```

<sub>Note: I couldn't actually test the code above with your example, since you didn't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which means that you should always include all required code but trying to keep your example as minimal as possible. In your case, you are using imported classes we know nothing about, but, in any way, they were completely unnecessary for the scope of your question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate. I apologize for the heavy code. the itemclicked() is indeed working. i am having errors with the exec-(). as soon as a choose item 1, it runs but this error appear:  in startProcedure window.exec_()
AttributeError: 'MainWindow_1' object has no attribute 'exec_' same when i choose item2 but then it shuts down

Comment: `exec_` is a method that exists only for QDialog (sub)classes; unfortunately, as said, you didn't provide all necessary code, so we don't know what the `ManagedWindow` class is and from what class it inherits. If it's not a QDialog subclass, it obviously doesn't have an `exec_` method.

Comment: I see. These classes are part of a package Pymeasure developed in the instrumentation community. It plots and queue experiments . class ManagedWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow): EDITOR = 'gedit'   def __init__(self, procedure_class, inputs=(), displays=(), x_axis=None, y_axis=None,
                 log_channel='', log_level=logging.INFO, parent=None, sequencer=False,
                 sequencer_inputs=None, sequence_file=None, inputs_in_scrollarea=False):
        super().__init__(parent)
        app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.quit)

Comment: I ll try to figure out base on your initial suggestion. thanks again

Comment: replacing window with self.window allows to run the code but still with this error message:RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question, providing an example that is as *minimal* as possible, while keeping it *reproducible* (see the link at the bottom of my answer). If you're using external modules that are not common, specify what they are/do. And remember that if my answer helped you to solve the specific issue of the question, you can set it as *accepted* by clicking on the checkmark symbol on the left (note that the fact that you got the above errors is not related to the question you asked).

Comment: Dear @musicamante i posted as suggested a new question and tried to simplify as much as possible the code.