# why a RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been delete appears after running a PyQt5 GUI to display other windows

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to let a user choose from a GUI a choice of procedures to be executed. Without the GUI section, i can execute the procedures and both appear at the same time on separate windows that i can run independently. Now i want the user to choose from a GUI which procedure to run first to avoid multiple windows open at the same time. While the procedures execute properly when i choose the second pushbutton i have this error message : ***RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted***. I ve seen this issue around and tried what has been proposed but without success. Following sugestions from
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302430/call-different-window-classes-into-a-main-window-in-pqt5-python], I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. Despite some specific packages utilized these are not responsible for the error observed and anyone should be able to run this code. the Mainwindow class is already using Qt for displaying a window but when used standalone i do not have any error. The error is inherent to the Ui_MainWindow(object) class, i also tried with item list the same issue occurs.The error appears each time i press Queue when choosing the Run 2 procedure.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
import sys
import random
import pandas as pd
from pymeasure.log import console_log
from pymeasure.display.Qt import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pymeasure.display.windows import ManagedWindow
from pymeasure.experiment import Procedure, Results
from pymeasure.experiment import IntegerParameter, FloatParameter, Parameter
import tempfile

# this class uses the Pymeasure package to run and display experiments here it s just generating a random number. the iterations 
#number being the input parameter on the window and one can queue several runs
# execute is the method generating the random number and Mainwindow is the dipsplay and the queue of the runs. the data are
# save in a temp file

class RandomProcedure_1(Procedure):

    iterations = IntegerParameter('Loop Iterations', default=10)

    DATA_COLUMNS = ['Iteration', 'Random Number']
    #
    def startup(self):
        log.info("Setting the time of the random number generator")
        random.seed(self.seed)

    def execute(self):
        log.info("Starting the loop of %d iterations" % self.iterations)
        for i in range(self.iterations):
            data = {
                'Iteration': i,
                'Random Number': random.randint(1, 50)
            }
            self.emit('results', data)
            log.debug("Emitting results: %s" % data)
            if self.should_stop():
                log.warning("Caught the stop flag in the procedure")
                break

class MainWindow_1(ManagedWindow):
# this define the window where the random number vs iteration plot is displayed
    def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow_1, self).__init__(
                procedure_class=RandomProcedure_1,
                inputs=['iterations'],
                displays=['iterations'], 
                x_axis='Iteration',
                y_axis='Random Number',
            )
            self.setWindowTitle('RandomProcedure_1')

    def queue(self, *, procedure=None):
        if procedure is None:
            procedure = self.make_procedure()
        filename = tempfile.mktemp()
        log.info("Constructing the Results with a data file: %s" % filename)
        results = Results(procedure, filename)
        experiment = self.new_experiment(results)
        self.manager.queue(experiment)

# the GUI with 2 pushbuttons for each procedure (here the same duplicated for simplicity)
# i also tried with a list of item but the same error occurs
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 160, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("EXP1")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startProcedure_1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 170, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("EXP2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.startProcedure_1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def startProcedure_1(self):
        self.window = MainWindow_1()
        self.window.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Procedures"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run 2"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: try move `self.window = MainWindow_1()` after `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. this works just fine. I also tested while calling 2 different procedure no errors anymore and datafiles saved properly. So if i understand one must make sure that all executions are in the constructor of the GUI?